# A control disappears from parent UserControl after UserControl's OnRepaint event

Tags: c#, user-controls, parent-child, repaint, onpaint

I have a `UserControl` which has a `button` on it.  On the `UserControl` `OnPaint` event I draw a rounded corner border (or a simple rectangle if the radius is zero) and then I fill the entire control. After these manipulations my `Button` (`btnClose`) disappears.
How do I make my `button` visible again?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Pen p = new Pen(new SolidBrush(this.BorderColor)))
    {
        if (borderRadius > 0)
        {
            DrawRoundRect(pe.Graphics, p, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1, borderRadius, this.FillColor);
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = this.FillColor;
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
        }
        btnClose.Location = new Point(this.Width - btnClose.Width - BTN_MARGIN_DELTA, BTN_MARGIN_DELTA);
    }
    base.OnPaint(pe);
}
```

Just in case, the DrawRoundRect function:

```
void DrawRoundRect(Graphics g, Pen p, float X, float Y, float width, float height, float radius, Color _fillColor)
{
    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        gp.AddLine(X + radius, Y, X + width - (radius * 2), Y);
        gp.AddArc(X + width - (radius * 2), Y, radius * 2, radius * 2, 270, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X + width, Y + radius, X + width, Y + height - (radius * 2));
        gp.AddArc(X + width - (radius * 2), Y + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X + width - (radius * 2), Y + height, X + radius, Y + height);
        gp.AddArc(X, Y + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 90, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X, Y + height - (radius * 2), X, Y + radius);
        gp.AddArc(X, Y, radius * 2, radius * 2, 180, 90);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(_fillColor))
        {
            g.FillPath(brush, gp);
            g.DrawPath(p, gp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the location code to the resize method:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
  btnClose.Location = new Point(this.Width - btnClose.Width - BTN_MARGIN_DELTA, BTN_MARGIN_DELTA);
}
```

Moving controls in a paint event could cause recursive calls to the paint event.  Only "paint" in a paint event.

Comment: Well, it was my mistake. It was a function that deletes all controls from UserControl. The code is provided below.
@LarsTech, anyway thanks, the OnResize helped to establish the correct position of button.

Answer (score 0):

I set `FillColor = Color.Gray`, `BorderColor = Color.Black`, `borderRadius = 5`, `BTN_MARGIN_DELTA = 2` and it seems to work without any problem. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I think the problem isn't these lines of code.

Comment: Well yes, shure. The problem was in other place where I made a total deletion of controls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my mistake. It was a function that deletes all controls from UserControl. So I filter the controls on removal.

```
void ClearControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (Control cc in Controls)
        {
            if (cc.Name.Contains(LINK_LABEL_FAMILY) || (cc.Name.Contains(LABEL_FAMILY)))
            {
                Controls.RemoveByKey(cc.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```